# String VS Byte[], memory usage

Tags: c#, string, memory

I have an application that uses a large amount of strings. So I have some problem of memory usage.
I know that one of the best solution in this case is to use a DB, but I cannot use this for the moment, so I am looking for others solutions.

In C# string are store in Utf16, that means I lost half of the memory usage compare to Utf8 (for the major part of my strings).
So I decided to use byte array of utf8 string. But to my surprise this solution took twice more memory space than simple strings in my application.

So I have done some simple test, but I want to know the opinion of experts to be sure.

**Test 1 : Fixed length strings allocation**

```
var stringArray = new string[10000];
var byteArray = new byte[10000][];
var Sb = new StringBuilder();
var utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
var stringGen = new Random(561651);
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
        Sb.Append((stringGen.Next(90)+32).ToString());
    }
    stringArray[i] = Sb.ToString();
    byteArray[i] = utf8.GetBytes(Sb.ToString());
    Sb.Clear();
}
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForFullGCComplete(5000);
```

Memory Usage

```
00007ffac200a510        1        80032 System.Byte[][]
00007ffac1fd02b8       56       152400 System.Object[]
000000bf7655fcf0      303      3933750      Free
00007ffac1fd5738    10004    224695091 System.Byte[]
00007ffac1fcfc40    10476    449178396 System.String
```

As we can see, bytes arrays take twice less memory space, no real surprise here.

**Test 2 : Random size string allocation (with a realistic length)**

```
var stringArray = new string[10000];
var byteArray = new byte[10000][];
var Sb = new StringBuilder();
var utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
var lengthGen = new Random(2138784);
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < lengthGen.Next(100); j++) {
        Sb.Append(i.ToString());
        stringArray[i] = Sb.ToString();
        byteArray[i] = utf8.GetBytes(Sb.ToString());
    }
    Sb.Clear();
}
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForFullGCComplete(5000);
```

Memory Usage

```
00007ffac200a510        1        80032 System.Byte[][]
000000be2aa8fd40       12        82784      Free
00007ffac1fd02b8       56       152400 System.Object[]
00007ffac1fd5738     9896       682260 System.Byte[]
00007ffac1fcfc40    10368      1155110 System.String
```

String takes a little less space than twice time the memory space of byte array. With shorter string I was expecting a greater overhead for strings.
But it seems that the opposite is, why?

**Test 3 : String model corresponding to my application**

```
var stringArray = new string[10000];
var byteArray = new byte[10000][];
var Sb = new StringBuilder();
var utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
var lengthGen = new Random();
for (int i=0; i < 10000; i++) {
    if (i%2 == 0) {
        for (int j = 0; j < lengthGen.Next(100000); j++) {
            Sb.Append(i.ToString());
            stringArray[i] = Sb.ToString();
            byteArray[i] = utf8.GetBytes(Sb.ToString());
            Sb.Clear();
        }
    } else {
        stringArray[i] = Sb.ToString();
        byteArray[i] = utf8.GetBytes(Sb.ToString());
        Sb.Clear();
    }
}
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForFullGCComplete(5000);
```

Memory Usage

```
00007ffac200a510        1        80032 System.Byte[][]
00007ffac1fd02b8       56       152400 System.Object[]
00007ffac1fcfc40     5476       198364 System.String
00007ffac1fd5738    10004       270075 System.Byte[]
```

Here strings take much less memory space than byte. This can be surprising, but I supposed that empty string are referenced only once. Is it? But I don't know if this can explain all that huge difference. Is it any other reason? What is the best solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This can be surprising, but I supposed that empty string are referenced only once.

Yes, an empty `StringBuilder` returns `string.Empty` as its result. The code snippet below prints `True`:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(sb.ToString(), string.Empty));
```

> But I don't know if this can explain all that huge difference.

Yes, this perfectly explains it. You are saving on 5,000 `string` objects. The difference in bytes is roughly 270,000-(198,000/2), so about 170 kBytes. Dividing by 5 you get 34 bytes per object, which is roughly the size of a pointer on a 32-bit system.

> What is the best solution?

Do the same thing: make yourself a `private static readonly` empty array, and use it each time that you get `string.Empty` from `sb.ToString()`:

```
private static readonly EmptyBytes = new byte[0];
...
else
{
    stringArray[i] = Sb.ToString();
    if (stringArray[i] == string.Empty) {
        byteArray[i] = EmptyBytes;
    } else {
        byteArray[i] = utf8.GetBytes(Sb.ToString());
    }
    Sb.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Why not use `String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringArray[i])`?

Comment: @MarkJansen It's only an illustration: I know for sure that `stringArray[i]` is empty in the `else` branch of the `if (i%2 == 0)` conditional, so I could have skipped the comparison with `string.Empty` altogether.

Comment: Interesting, indeed use an empty byte reference improve memory usage a lot.
I forgot to say in my post, than I was in 64 bits and the unit is bytes. Anyway this doesn't change that idea of your explanation, even if I found that 34 bytes for a pointer it's a lot, (even more with the 26 bytes overhead of each string).
I have already lost the size of 10K pointer (80032 KB ie 25% of the usefull memory size) with System.Byte[][].
Is there any way to avoid the usage of so much indirection ? Maybe not with array of bytes.

Comment: @Edeen You could squeeze even more data into the same number of bytes by rolling your own memory "allocator", which is simple enough if your strings never change. Essentially, you could allocate all your bytes upfront in one big chunk, and then parcel it out into stings, storing the indexes where the next string begins. This does not work if you need to replace strings with new strings of different length.